# Mostrar datos de un objeto en concreto

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int opcion, posi = 0;

     Perro perro1 = new Perro("Luke", "25/10/2022",EstadoAnimal.VIVO, RazaPerro.YORKSHIRE_TERRIER,ColorPerroGato.MARRON);
     Gato gato1 = new Gato("Mimi", "18/05/2021", EstadoAnimal.ENFERMO,PelajeGato.ASPERO, ColorPerroGato.GRIS);
     Loro loro1 = new Loro("Perico", "03/01/2020",EstadoAnimal.VIVO,1.5,OrigenLoro.AFRICA);
     Perro perro2 = new Perro("Toby", "23/05/2019",EstadoAnimal.ENFERMO, RazaPerro.HUSKY_SIBERIANO,ColorPerroGato.GRIS);
     Loro loro2 = new Loro("Yaco", "07/08/2018",EstadoAnimal.MUERTO,1.2,OrigenLoro.AMERICA_CENTRAL);
     Gato gato2 = new Gato("Rocky", "15/02/2017", EstadoAnimal.VIVO,PelajeGato.RIZADO, ColorPerroGato.NARANJA);

     animales[0] = perro1;
     animales[1] = gato1;
     animales[2] = loro1;
     animales[3] = perro2;
     animales[4] = loro2;
     animales[5] = gato2;
```

Tengo estos objetos creados. También tengo un menú en el que me pide mostrar un animal en concreto. Cosa que he estado probando y no soy capaz de sacarlo.

```
public static void animalConcreto(Animal animal){
        if (animal instanceof Perro)
            System.out.println(animal.getNombre(),animal.getFechaNac(),animal.getEstado(),((Perro) animal).getRaza(),((Perro) animal).getColorPerro());


    }
```

He probado con esto y tampoco me funciona, lo que intento es sacar con un sout el animal en concreto ya sea perro gato o loro.
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

para que la función `animalConcreto` valide adecuadamente con `instanceof` es necesario declarar los objetos como parte de la misma instancia, en este caso `Animal` ya que si haces la instancia de cada objeto, dicho objeto solo será comparable conforme fue creado y no con la validación de la clase padre.

En este caso la forma para declarar tus objetos debe ser:

```
Animal perro1 = new Perro("Luke", "25/10/2022",EstadoAnimal.VIVO, RazaPerro.YORKSHIRE_TERRIER,ColorPerroGato.MARRON);
Animal gato1 = new Gato("Mimi", "18/05/2021", EstadoAnimal.ENFERMO,PelajeGato.ASPERO, ColorPerroGato.GRIS);
Animal loro1 = new Loro("Perico", "03/01/2020",EstadoAnimal.VIVO,1.5,OrigenLoro.AFRICA);
Animal perro2 = new Perro("Toby", "23/05/2019",EstadoAnimal.ENFERMO, RazaPerro.HUSKY_SIBERIANO,ColorPerroGato.GRIS);
Animal loro2 = new Loro("Yaco", "07/08/2018",EstadoAnimal.MUERTO,1.2,OrigenLoro.AMERICA_CENTRAL);
Animal gato2 = new Gato("Rocky", "15/02/2017", EstadoAnimal.VIVO,PelajeGato.RIZADO, ColorPerroGato.NARANJA);
```

En esta [liga](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) encontrarás un ejemplo de como se hace la comparación

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, He mirado el enlace que me has puesto y lo entiendo. Pero aun no entiendo en como mostrar por pantalla un animal en concreto, es decir poder sacar toda la informacion de perro1 por pantalla o perro2 o loro1, su nombre fecha, etc.

Comment: Por lo que entiendo, quieres hacer una búsqueda dentro del arreglo de animales, igual si no tienes un identificador puedes hacer la búsqueda por algún atributo de los objetos en el arreglo. Si tienes **Java8** puedes hacer: `public static void findAnimalByName(Animal[] list, String name) {
    Animal concreto = Arrays.stream(list).filter(x -> x.getNombre().equals(name)).findFirst().orElse(null);
    System.out.println(animal.getNombre(),animal.getFechaNac(),animal.getEstado(),((Perro) animal).getRaza(),((Perro) animal).getColorPerro());
}`

Answer (score 0):

@Xstrick23, puedes crear una clase Animal, que contenga todos los métodos de los distintos animales, luego declaras clases vacías (Perro, Gato, etc) que heredan a Animal.

```
public class Animal {
   public Animal( String pelaje, String origen, String nomb, String raz ) {   
       PelajeGato = pelaje;
       OrigenLoro = origen;
       nombre = nomb;
       raza = raz; 
   } 

   private PelajeGato; 
   private OrigenLoro;
   private nombre;
   private raza;

   public getNombre() {
      return ;
   }

   public getPelajeGato() {
      return ;
   }

   public getOrigenLoro() {
      return ;
   }

   public getRaza() {
      return ;
   }
}

public class Perro extends Animales { 
   public Perro( String nombre, String raza ) {
       //    pelaje, origen, nombre, raza
       super( "", "", nombre, raza );
   } 
}
public class Gato extends Animal {
   public Gato( String pelaje, String nombre ) {
       //    pelaje, origen, nombre, raza
       super( pelaje "", nombre, "" );
   } 
}

public class Loro extends Animal {
   public Loro( String origen, String nombre ) {
       //    pelaje, origen, nombre, raza
       super( "", origen, nombre, "" );
   } 
}

    //en otra clase


public static void animalConcreto( Animal animal ) {
    if (animal instanceof Perro) {
        System.out.println( animal.getNombre(), animal.getRaza() );
    }
    if (animal instanceof Gato) {
       System.out.println( animal.getNombre(), animal.getPelajeGato() );
    }
    if (animal instanceof Loro) {
       System.out.println( animal.getNombre(),animal.getOrigenLoro() );
    }
}
```

De esta forma, casi siempre trabajas con "Animal", despreocupandote de que tipo de animal es, incluso en aquellos atributos comunes, los puedes obtener sin verificar el tipo, por ejemplo, todos los animales tienen nombre, osea que **animal.getNombre()** funciona, solo cuando quieres acceder a atributos específicos verificas el tipo.
El ejemplo está incompleto, agrega los atributos que faltan en "Animal", y corrige los constructores.

Una variante a esto, sería quitar los atributos específicos de "Animal", y colocarlos en sus respectivas clases (con sus respectivos geters), osea "Animal" tendría solo los atributos **nombre, fecha y estado, "Perro" tendría **raza y colorPerroGato**, "Gato" -> **pelaje y colorPerroGato**, y "Loro" -> **gradoDelLoro?, origen**, y modificando las llamadas a "super".
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: `class Animales` debería ser `class Animal` puesto que cada clase se refiere a un animal concreto. Por lo general las clases que definen un *"Objeto"* específico se escriben en singular. Además, si te fijas en el método recibe un parámetro de tipo `Animal`, con lo cual se puede asumir que ya tiene dicha clase... si no, además, no le dejaría añadir todas esas clases diferentes a un mismo array, a no ser que fuese un array de su superclase común.

Comment: @Benito-B, gracias por la acotación, ya corrijo.

Comment: Como detalle, tampoco es correcto tener en la clase super los atributos pertenecientes a las clases hijas. Un `Animal` no necesita tener información de `PelajeGato` puesto que un Loro no tendrá ese atributo. Esos atributos se declaran en la clase hija, la cual tiene acceso a atributos del padre tanto como atributos propios. De esa manera evitas que un Loro tenga pelos en vez de plumas :)

Comment: @Benito-B, justamente agregué esa opción, ahora bien, en la práctica, suelo utilizar este enfoque ya que me no me "molesta" que el perro tenga plumas, y me facilita la gestión del programa... y un poco por vago, eso si, hay que tener mucho cuidado a la hora de trabajar con estos objetos, porque si como entiendo que lo estás pensando, le pido el color de las plumas al perro.....

Comment: tal vez una razón de mi enfoque, es que trabajo en solitario, sino creo que haría lo tu dices.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por las respuestas al final lo que he hecho ha sido esto.

```
public static void animalConcreto(int posicion){
            for (int i = 0; i < animales.length ; i++) {
                if (animales[posicion] == null){
                    System.err.println("No se ha encontrado ningun animal con ese posicionamiento");
                    break;
                }else{
                    if (animales[posicion] != null){
                        System.out.println(animales[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
```

Y luego por teclado le digo la posición que quiero mostrar.